# PHP: Get all groups in a regex

Tags: php, regex

The **question** is: How to do this using only (and a single) regex? Is it possible?

**Explanation**: I have an array like this:

```
array
(
   [0] => 'code1-{1,5}{a,c}',
   [1] => 'code2-{3,6}{s,q}'
)
```

and what I want to do is to get, using a regex, all the values grouped like:

```
code1
1,5
a,c
```

I know that I can get all the data inside the `{...}` using this regex:

`'/\{([^\}]*)\}/i'`

Besides I know that I can get the string before the dash using this one

`/(.*?)\-/i`

What I don't know is if it's possible to merge this two regex. Infact, if I have this regex

`'/(.*?)\-\{([^\}]*)\}/i'`

I can't get all the data I need. I also know that I can do something like this:

`'/(.*?)\-\{([^\}]*)\}\{([^\}]*)\}/i'`

but if the format of the input will change to say 10 {...} groups, it's no so elegant to have 10 group of the form `\{([^\}]*)\}` and it's not the point of my question.

Here are the code that I'm trying:

**First regex**(`'/\{([^\}]*)\}/i'`): http://ideone.com/mN3T2

**Merged regex**(`'/(.*?)\-\{([^\}]*)\}/i'`): http://ideone.com/gMdOa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: After OP's edit

I don't believe you can merge those two regular expressions and still retain the ability to loop through the matches of the form `{1,5}`. I think it is better to use two separate regular expressions for this purpose, one to capture  `coden` and another to iterate over matches of text between `{}`.

One way to do this is to split over `-` like this

`$result = preg_split('/-/m', 'code1-{1,5}{a,c}');`

and then you get `code1` as the first entry and 
`{1,5}{a,c}` as the second entry. Now apply your regex

`\{([^\}]*)\}` over the second entry and iterate over the matches.